# DynamoDB Sort and select top 20 records

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I wanted to get records like top 10 or 20 basically some configurable number which are sorted based on a date field stored as ISO-8601 format `uuuu-MM-dd` after applying some filters.

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Data")
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Data {

    private LocalDate date;
    @Setter
    private Long number;
    @Setter
    private STATUS status;

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    @DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = LocalDateConverter.class)
    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    @DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = LocalDateConverter.class)
    public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @DynamoDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = "idx_Data_number")
    public Long getCompetitionId() {
        return number;
    }

    @DynamoDBTypeConvertedEnum
    @DynamoDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = "idx_Data_status")
    public STATUS getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
}
```

I need to get say 20 records sorted based on date field after filtering based on number and multiple status. I was using `ScanRequest` to basically filter the records. Now I want to limit the results and get top records based on the date.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DataRepositoryImpl implements DataRepository {
 private final DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper;
 private final AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB;

 @Override
 public List<Data> findAll(Long number, List<String> status) {
    Condition numberCondition = new Condition()
            .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ)
            .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withN(String.valueOf(number)));

    List<AttributeValue> attributeValues = newArrayList();
    status.forEach(s -> attributeValues.add(new AttributeValue().withS(s)));
    Condition statusCondition = new Condition()
            .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.IN)
            .withAttributeValueList(attributeValues);

    Map<String, Condition> conditions = newHashMap();
    conditions.put("number", numberCondition);
    conditions.put("status", statusCondition);

    ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
            .withTableName("Data")
            .withScanFilter(conditions)
            .withConditionalOperator(ConditionalOperator.AND);

    ScanResult scanResult = amazonDynamoDB.scan(scanRequest);
    return dynamoDBMapper.marshallIntoObjects(Data.class, scanResult.getItems());
    }
}
```

Comment: DynamoDB isn't really designed to be used for things like that. It's more a key value store.

Answer (score 3):

DynamoDB sorts the data only by **SORT KEY** attribute.

DynamoDB doesn't have a feature to sort the data by any attribute (i.e. any non-key attributes or partition key attribute) except `sort key`.

> Partition key and sort key – Referred to as a composite primary key,
>   this type of key is composed of two attributes. The first attribute is
>   the partition key, and the second attribute is the sort key. DynamoDB
>   uses the partition key value as input to an internal hash function.
>   The output from the hash function determines the partition (physical
>   storage internal to DynamoDB) in which the item will be stored. All
>   items with the same partition key are stored together, in sorted order
>   by sort key value.

DynamoDB stores the data in multiple partitions. Like RDBMS, it doesn't have any `ORDER BY` clause as well. However, it does have `ScanIndexForward` option which can be applied only for `Sort` key attribute.

> ScanIndexForward — (Boolean) Specifies the order for index traversal:
>   If true (default), the traversal is performed in ascending order; if
>   false, the traversal is performed in descending order.

Comment: Can you help me with some coding exmples

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can achieve this using DynamoDB. You will have to order and filter the result using application code.

The only way DynamoDB will return ordered results is if you use a sort key. However your initial query is multi dimensional (one number, many status'), so you cannot create a partition that would work in this case.

If you wanted to query on say a single number, and order by date, you could use number as your partition key and a new 'date as long number' attribute as your sort key. DynamoDB keys can only be [String,Number or Binary attributes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_KeySchemaElement.html). I assume your LocalDateConverter changes the date to a string, so this wouldn't make a good sort key. However, you could add a new attribute that was a number and represented the date in YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format, which would naturally sort in the correct order. You could then use DynamoDB ScanIndexForward function and limit your result set to a given number of items.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `Limit` in your scan. `ScanRequest#setLimit`

> The maximum number of items to evaluate (not necessarily the number of
>   matching items). If DynamoDB processes the number of items up to the
>   limit while processing the results, it stops the operation and returns
>   the matching values up to that point, and a key in LastEvaluatedKey to
>   apply in a subsequent operation, so that you can pick up where you
>   left off.

But I doubt dynamodb provide sort on any key in `scan`.

You can create Local Index, and that will help you to retrieve with limit as well as sorted.